# Linq2db entity framework update query for dynamic table and column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, linq2db

I want a generic query for all the tables using [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

I have 5 things.
 1. TableName
 2. ColumnaName
 3. ColumnValue
 4. Where condition column name
 5. Where condition column value.

So far what I am trying practically is something like below.

```
public void update(string entity, string attribute, object value, string whereAttribute, string whereAttributeValue)
{
    projectContext.Set<object>().ToLinqToDBTable().TableName(entity)
        .Where(t => t[whereAttribute] == whereAttributeValue) // This is not working.
        .Set(t => t[attribute], value) // so far it is not giving any build error.
        .Update();
}
```

but it is not working. how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Linq2db has dynamic properties feature that you probably could use here, but it needs to know entity type:

```cs
public void update<TEntity>(string entity, string attribute, object value, string whereAttribute, string whereAttributeValue)
    where TEntity : class
{
    projectContext.GetTable<TEntity>()
        .TableName(entity)
        .Where(t => Sql.Property<TEntity>(t, whereAttribute).Equals(whereAttributeValue))
        .Set(t => Sql.Property<TEntity>(t, attribute), value)
        .Update();
}
```

Comment: I don't have TEntity :(